# SQL LAG over 2 dimensions

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say I have a "two-dimensional" table:

```
 Y\X  1  2  3
 1   10 20 30
 2   40 50 60
 3   70 80 90
```

For each element, I want to find its adjacent left, up, and up-left elements:

Left:

```
 Y\X  1  2  3
 1  Null 20 30
 2  Null 40 50
 3  Null 70 80
```

Up:

```
 Y\X  1  2  3
 1 Null Null Null
 2   10 20 30
 3   40 50 60
```

Up-left:

```
 Y\X  1  2  3
 1 Null Null Null
 2 Null 10 20
 3 Null 40 50
```

I tried the following query:

```
select X, Y, value,
        lag(value,1) over (partition by X order by Y) as up_value,
        lag(value,1) over (partition by Y order by X) as left_value,
        lag(value,4) over (order by X,Y) as up_left_value
from tt
order by X,Y
```

It did return "left" and "up" correctly, but not exactly for "up-left" (highlighted as "WRONG"):

```
    X   Y   value   up_value    left_value  up_left_value
1   1   1   10  NL  NL  NL
2   1   2   20  10  NL  NL
3   1   3   30  20  NL  NL
4   2   1   40  NL  10  NL
5   2   2   50  40  20  10
6   2   3   60  50  30  20
7   3   1   70  NL  40  *30*(<- WRONG, should be "NL")
8   3   2   80  70  50  40
9   3   3   90  80  60  50
```

My play ground is here: https://rextester.com/BXJ66520

How do I fix the "up-left" problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For upleft, you want the "left" of the "up" (or the "up" of the left), so use two steps:

```
select t.*,
       lag(up) over (partition by y order by x) as upleft
from (select x, y, value,
             lag(value) over (partition by x order by y) as up,             
             lag(value) over (partition by y order by x) as left
      from t
     ) t;
```

Comment: I thought about this solution, but actually my search is 3-dimensial which will make the query very long with two steps. Any easy solution to put some constraints on "ORDER BY"?

Comment: @HailiangZhang . . . I don't see why that would have a dramatic impact on performance.  You should try it.

Comment: Thanks! Performance-wise it's OK, except the query is more bulky.